# ZAP Scan progress is 0% while trying to run ZAP Scan from Remote Jenkins Server ( External Jenkins Server ) by Specifying ZAP host as node

Tags: zap

[image]We have configured local Jenkins instance(Installed the required ZAP plugins) where ZAP is Installed and tried to perform ZAP Scan using Jenkins Job. ZAP Scan is happening from the local Jenkins Instance and we can able see the progress and scan is getting completed.
We need to move this Jenkins configuration to Remote Jenkins Instance where our other deployment Jobs are present. 
We have created node for ZAP Host and when we are trying to run ZAP Scan,The Scan is getting initiated but the progress is 0% .
I checked the firewall settings in the ZAP host. Seems like it is not firewall issue.
I have set the proxies in ZAP, Jenkins and Browser.
We are using localhost:8080 which is default. If we are changing that to IP:8080 by adding IP:8080 in local proxies it is not working.
Do we need to make any other changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured ZAP to accept remote connections?

By default ZAP will now also only allow connections from the local machine. You can set which IP addresses can connect to the API using the command line:

> -config api.addrs.addr.name=123.456.789.123

If you are using ZAP in a completely isolated environment you can allow all IP addresses to connect to the ZAP API using:

> -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true

You will also need to set or disable the API key

For more details see this FAQ: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQremote

Comment: Thanks for the response@Simon Bennets.

We have tried this from ZAP Tool under API section not from command line. We have given the IP of the Host from where we are running the ZAP.
We have tried with enabling API key and also by disabling API key.But it didnt work.
Will try to allow all the IP addresses from Command line.
Is there any other specific settings required.

Comment: It wouldn't be the IP of ZAP that you need to add, it'd be the IP of the host (Jenkins?)  that's interacting with the ZAP API.

Comment: Thanks kingthorin. Yes we have specified under API section to allow all hosts to connect to ZAP. We are getting listening to 8080 message in Jenkins console but the scan progress is still 0%.

Comment: Hi even after disabling the api key -config api.disablekey=true when i am initiating Jenkins Job the value is getting overridden by Api key as ZAPlugin in config,xml .   Below is the error message we are getting in console : Request to API URL http://zap/xml/core/action/shutdown/?apikey=ZAPROXY-PLUGIN from IP  not permitted. This is the command which is getting executed on initiation of Jenkins Job : -daemon -host IP -port 8080 -config api.key=ZAPROXY-PLUGIN -dir C:\workspace\ZAP_Test -installdir "C:\Program Files\OWASP\Zed Attack Proxy" .

Comment: I also tried to change the value in config.xml..                                                     The value is getting change on initiation of Jenkins Job.Is there a way to disable the api using ZAP Plugin in Jenkins